# Which ArcGIS product gives full 3D terrain navigation and (flight) simulation?

Tags: 3d, terrain

I looked at the ArcGIS ESRI website and find that 100% of the screenshots depicts a 2D map with at most relief shading.

Is there any product ArcGIS or not that gives real 3D terrain visualisation capable of things like flight simulation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ArcGlobe
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=ArcGlobe_3D_display_environment

Lots of RAM required.

Though Google Earth might be a better option. (as comes with a flight sim)
http://earth.google.com/intl/en/userguide/v5/flightsim/index.html

Comment: Seconded that Google Earth will be better. The rendering (at least in 9.2, the last time I tried it) in ArcGlobe is horrible. I tried every setting I could think of and the final rendered product still didn't look anywhere near the quality of on-the-fly Google Earth rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Both ArcGlobe & ArcScene are capable of providing 3D terrain Visualization, but the Navigation tools are horrendous.

You could use Google Earth, but when you load your own data, the capabilities are limited:You cannot add your own DEM, The memory consumption goes up with the amount of images that you load, and garbage collection in memory is limited.

For a 3D modelling project, we ended up using an Hybrid approach. We used the scene control for high precision Analysis & general display, while we used the Google earth 3D Plugin for showing large areas.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Geoweb3d](http://www.geoweb3d.com), it has ArcGIS Engine embedded.  It is GPU based for high performance, uses native GIS source data, and supports simulation (DIS, feeds, etc) out of the box. They have a free 2 week evaluation.

Comment: "Forbidden - Users from your country are not permitted to browse this site"; nice product

Answer (score 0):

[NASA](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/) [WorldWind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/features.html) is another option, capable of using SRTM to get 3D visualisation.